# How to find the inverse distribution function of a mixture random variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X,Y, Z$ be three random variables such that 
$$F_Z(x) = wF_X(x) + (1-w)F_Y(x)$$
Then is it true that
$$F_{Z}^{-1}(x) = wF_{X}^{-1}(x) + (1-w)F_{Y}^{-1}(x)?$$

Or, how do we fix the $F_{Z}^{-1}$?

Thanks everyone for you cooperation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $F_Z(z) = w\,F_X(z)+(1-w)\,F_Y(z)$

Does $F_Z^{-1}(u) = w\,\,F_X^{-1}(z)+(1-w)\,F_Y^{-1}(z)$

---

Let us examine the case where $X\sim\mathcal U(0;1)$ and $Y\sim\mathcal U(1;2)$

Then $F_Z(z) = wz\,\mathbf 1_{z\in[0;1)}+((1-w)z+2w-1)\,\mathbf 1_{z\in[1;2)}+\,\mathbf 1_{z\in[2;\infty)}$

So $F_Z^{-1}(u) = \begin{cases}u/w &: 0< u< w \\ 1+ (u - w)/(1-w) & : w\le u< 1 \\ \mathsf{undef} & :\textsf{elsewhere} \end{cases}$

But $F_X^{-1}(u) = \begin{cases}u&:0<u<1 \\\textsf{undefined}&:\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}\\ F_Y^{-1}(u) = \begin{cases}1+u&:0<u<1 \\\textsf{undefined}&:\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$

---

**tl;dr** No; it does not in general.  At least one counterexample exists.